# Google Sheets URLFetchApp not defined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I couldn't find any help on the issue above, so I'm posting here seeking help for this.

I'm writing a script on Google Sheets/Script that uses the URLFetchApp function, and it returns an error code saying "URLFetchApp" is not defined.

```
function myFunction() {

    var res = URLFetchApp.fetch("https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/tradesymbol=.BVOL&");
    var content = res.getContentText();
    Logger.log(res);
    Logger.log(content);

}
```

Comment: The reason of the error is a spelling mistake. Please modify from ``URLFetchApp.fetch(`` to ``UrlFetchApp.fetch(``. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app By this, the error of ``URLFetchApp not defined`` is removed.

Comment: Thanks! it helped!

Comment: Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved.